# how do I enter the text in gedit linux entered in the java?

Tags: java, linux

I have my project going on.In which i have to accept the touchpad co-ordinates and based on that I'm trying to develop a keyboard over lay on the touchpad.I'm using java as my language.

And developing it through linux. wanted to know how do i enter the text in gedit directly working on java. Is there a way through which i can enter the text recognized in the gedit?

(text editor- suggest if any other text editor possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet is an example of how to generate a Keypress event in Java.

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);

  }
}
```

The following official Java Tutorial [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) provides an example of how to write a listener for mouse events.

What you want to do is generate keyPress events based on the location of the MouseListener on a Click event.

In your `MousePressed` handler you will get the x and y coordinates using MouseEvent's `getXOnScreen()` and `getYOnScreen()` methods, then depending on their values generate the relevant  `KeyPress` with robot.

If you actually wanted the raw touchpad coordinate location, rather than the location of the cursor on the screen from the touchpad, I don't think you could do that with Java.

As **Kazekage Gaara** posted, runtime and process will start gedit for you and then you can use generated mouse events and keypress events to type into it.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("/usr/bin/gedit");
```

Why would you want to type into a text editor and save the file, rather than just inputing the characters that would be generated by the keypress straight into the file using [standard Java IO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html), I don't know.

If you are starting external programs to do these things, then you could get the touchpad coordinates from the external program `xev`.

Comment: Actually i'm tryng to find the raw co-ordinates through linux drivers and then tryng to enter it in a file and rad it through java....actually i wanted to enter the text inthe geedit(or text editor) running on the system without closing the editor

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) class and [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) method ( and it's variations ) for starting a sub-process (gedit in your case) and working with it while executing your Java program.

**Edit:**
Assuming you are working on Windows and using notepad and all your coordinates are stored in a file called test.txt . Here's a code snippet that will get you started towards what you want :

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe C:\\test.txt");
```

Comment: do you think saving the document and then re running the document with the modification will do?

Comment: It should do, as long as you handle your subprocess properly.

Comment: actually i'm a newbee to this i would sure do that when i get to a mark where my reputation allows me to do that...sorry...i'm eagerly waiting for that for your answers have helped me...